# Protective + noun+ing vs protecting + noun + ing

Tags: grammar

Is it *protective* or *protecting* covering that provides protection?

And why is it a *protected* area, not *protecting* or *protective*?

When should we use *-ive* or *-ing*?

Answer (score 1):

If something (call it **X**) described as ***protected***, that means *something or somebody else* is making sure that **X** doesn't suffer.

But if **X** is ***protective*** or ***protecting***, that means **X** is making sure *"something else"* isn't damaged.

By the normal rules of grammar, both suffixes (***-ive*** and ***ing***) can be used to generate adjectives like this from verbs (***protect***, here, but it's the same with ***to act, active, acting; to depress, depressive, depressing; to reflect, reflective, reflecting;*** etc., etc.).

Not all verbs can take *both* suffixes, and sometimes there's a bit more morphological change involved (***to invade, invasive, invading***). And sometimes there's nothing to choose between the two different forms (they're considered equivalent in meaning, and may even be equally commonly used).

But what usually happens in English is that if two "different" words superficially might be thought to mean the same thing, people will start using them in different ways, and thus *create* a distinction. Sometimes it's just *we always use this version, not the other one* - but then circumstances change, and suddenly the version that people *didn't* use becomes useful for referring to some specific subtly different context.

---

In the case of ***protective***, that's normally reserved today for contexts where the entire *purpose* of **X** is to provide protection. So it's definitely ***protective paint*** if you're talking about an "anti-rust" coating, for example. And if you referred to ***protecting paint***, people might suppose you were talking about some paint that was primarily applied for decorative purposes, but which fortuitously turns out to be useful for protecting the underlying material as well.

---

While we're on the subject, we can also consider the "adjectival noun" usage in contexts like *The storekeeper had to pay [**protection money**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/protection-money.html)* and *This contract includes a [**data protection clause**](https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/8-200-2079?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true&comp=pluk&bhcp=1)*. I doubt anyone could say exactly what it is about those two (semantically, very different) contexts that makes the ***-tion***-derived adjectival noun the standard choice there.

Sometimes you just have to learn the prevalence and likely meanings for all the different derived forms of any given base word. But bear in mind that even for the specific word under consideration, the full OED has many different subdefinitions for each of ***protective, protecting, protection*** (not to mention several more for the verb ***to protect*** itself).